# Textbox.text parameter not getting passed to db connection C# application

Tags: c#, sql, database, textbox

I'm working on an windows application that has a log in page where the user enters in their sql connection credentials user name and password.  Then they can upload data from excel sheets to db.  The problem I'm having when the user presses the run button which starts the process of opening the file and reading the data than eventually passes the values to DB and when it tries to connect to the db it fails because he returns null for username and password.  How can I make my program remember those values when passing them to the db connection part?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace NewTestDataReader
{
   public partial class DataUploader : Form
{
    public DataUploader()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal string m_susername;
    public string username { get { return this.m_susername; } set { this.m_susername = value; } }
    internal string m_spassword;
    public string password { get { return this.m_spassword; } set { this.m_spassword = value; } }

   private void RunButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(scan));
        oThread.Start();   
        password = userPasswordInputTextBox.Text;
        username = userNameInputTextBox.Text;
    }
    private void scan()
    {
        ///scans the file and goes to FileReader function in separate   TestDataReader.cs file
     }
  }
}

 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Data;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

 namespace TestDataReader 
{
public class SheetOneDataReader : DataUploader
{
  //parameters it reads from the excel sheet
    internal string m_sName;
    public string Name { get { return m_sName; } set { m_sName = value; } }

    internal string m_sAddress;
    public string Address{ get { return m_sAddress; } set { m_sAddress = value; } }

public void SaveSheetOneDataToDB()
    {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UL_ExcelFirstSheetData");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = this.Name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = this.Address;

      String connectionString;  
       SqlConnection cnn;        
        connectionString = "data source = 10.5.200.300";
        connectionString += ";initial catalog = Excel_data" + ";Persist Security Info=True";
        **connectionString += ";user id=" +  username;  //returns null 
        connectionString += ";password=" + password;   //returns null**
         cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
        }
        catch
        {}         
    }
}

 public class FileReader
  {
      public static bool ReadFile(FileInfo oInfo)
    {
        try
        {
          //goes to SheetOneDataReader on top
           SheetOneDataReader oDataSheetOne = new SheetOneDataReader();
           oDataSheetOne.Name =  //values from excel sheet
           oDataSheetOne.Address = //values from the excel sheet
           oDataSheetOne.SaveSheetOneDataToDB();

        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: What kind of application is this? windows/web/mobile ?

Comment: it is the first time am seeing a code like this totally confused,

Comment: We're not seeing the connection when you call RunButton_Click and when you call SaveSheetOneDataToDB.

Comment: According to this example you are not executing the command, nor handling the connection properly, is this code directly from your application?

Comment: @csensoft it's a windows application

Comment: @LarsTech I just omitted that part of the code.  The application works if I just provide it with a user name and password so that part works.  I'm just trying to change it so it gets the username and password from the log in page instead.

Comment: you need to pass the value from DataUploader to SaveSheetOneDataToDB method. as it owns a different copy

Answer (score 0):

The `username` and `password` properties belong to class `DataUploader` which you are inheriting in `SheetOneDataReader`. You set the values for these properties in `RunButton_Click` which reside under `DataUploader`. When you inherit that class it's going to reinitialize those two properties with null and not going to preserver the values you assigned in some other class.

Rather set values for the below properties within your `SheetOneDataReader` class and that's where you need them to connect to the DB.

```
password = userPasswordInputTextBox.Text;
username = userNameInputTextBox.Text;
```

Or you may have to resort to some other way of state management like `Session` or `ViewState`

Comment: I tired to add properties in SheetOneDataReader but when I use the lines to set the values it complains about userPasswordInputTextBox.Text so that's why I was trying to set it in DataUploader

Comment: It says The name 'userNameInputTextBox' does not exist in the current context

Comment: This is because `SheetOneDataReader` doesn't directly have access to the `form` controls. Is `SheetOneDataReader` a separate `.cs` file inheriting `DataUploader`? An alternate way is to assign `Session["username"] = userNameInputTextBox.Text;` from whatever class you have access to the textbox controls and use it elsewhere you need. If you don't want to that then better structure your classes to share the members between them as each request will create a new instance of the class.

Comment: I figured it out.  I just declared it as in DataUploader              internal static string m_susername;
        public static string username { get { return m_susername; } set { m_susername = value; } }
        internal static string m_spassword;
        public static string password { get { return m_spassword; } set { m_spassword = value; } }                                       and I was able to call it to SaveSheetOneDataToDB  by DataUploader.password

Comment: You may use static variables for this. Those variables will be shared between all requests, regardless of the client. I very much doubt that's what you want.

Comment: I have tailored the windows application so only when the credentials are correct they can use the application/use the buttons that are on another tab.  I just needed to leverage the same credentials when the data needs to be inserted.  So the static variable works perfectly for this case.  But I see your point of how this could cause problems in other situations.